# Unlapping optional error in UIView

Tags: swift3, uiview, option-type

I wanted to programmatically control the menu view so I tried the following:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var menuView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func menuBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("menuBtn")

        print(type(of: menuView!)) // <- `Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

    }

}
```

And click the button, console says
`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)`

[image]

Both are connected to ViewController.

How can I get `print(type(of: menuView!))`?

===============================================================

ps.

I've simplified my real problem. this is my real code:

button on ViewController.Swift

```
@IBAction func openModal(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("open btn clicked")
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuViewController") as! MenuViewController

        self.addChildViewController(vc)
        self.view.addSubview(vc.contentView!) /// <- This cause problem

    }
```

MenuViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        view.isOpaque = false
    }

    @IBAction func closeBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("close btn clicked")
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

and Why I wan't using it:

[image]

I can't scrolling when menuView appeared.. I want to use the buttons in the menu view and scroll at the same time.

Comment: Make sure your outlets are connected to the storyboard correctly and I think you dont need ! when you use in your code because they are already implicitly unwrapped when you connect the outlet

Comment: oh.. Thank you for answer. It is used that way.